# Python: recursion in finding the power of X

Tags: python, recursion

```
def pow(X, N):

    # base case
    if N == 0:
        return 1
    
    # recurssion call
    temp = pow(X, N//2) 
    
    # if N is odd then we will have to multiply x
    if N%2 == 1:
        return temp*temp*X
    
    return temp*temp
```

Algorithm
time complexity : O(log n)
space complexity : O(log n)

can someone help me with this code …mainly I want to know what is the role of return statements in this as i get confused a lot from a beginner POV and what is N//2 ?

Comment: Role of return statements - well, that's basic information about functions... If you mean why there are two: if N is divisible by 2, let's write it as N=2k (so k=N//2) and see: `X^(2k) == (X^k)*(X^k)`. In case of odd N, let's write N=2k+1 (again, k=N//2), then `X^(2k+1) = (X^k)*(X^k)*X`. X^k is being calculated in recursive call (temp)

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is a recursive algorithm to calculate the power of a number X raised to the exponent N. It uses the concept of exponentiation by squaring for optimization.

The code has a base case where if the exponent N is 0, it returns 1 since any number raised to the power of 0 is 1.

In the recursive part, the code makes a recursive call by dividing the exponent N by 2 (N//2) and storing the result in the variable `temp`. This recursive call helps break down the problem into smaller subproblems.

After the recursive call, there are two return statements:

- If the exponent N is odd, an extra multiplication of the base X is required. In this case, the function returns `temp * temp * X`, combining the result of the recursive call (`temp * temp`) with the extra multiplication (`* X`).
- If the exponent N is even, no extra multiplication is needed. The function simply returns `temp * temp`, which is the result of the recursive call squared.

The use of return statements ensures that the computed values are returned to previous recursive calls and ultimately to the initial call, providing the final result.

The time complexity of the algorithm is O(log N) because the exponent is divided by 2 in each recursive call. The space complexity is also O(log N) due to the recursive nature of the algorithm.

Overall, this algorithm efficiently calculates the power of a number using recursion and exponentiation by squaring technique.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the role of return statements in this

You refer to these statements:

```
if N%2 == 1:
    return temp*temp*X
return temp*temp
```

Here the result of a recursive call (that has already come back with a result) is used to define the final value.

> what is `N//2`

It is integer division. Alternatively you could write it as `N>>1`. So if `N` is odd the remainder of 1 is ignored at this step. But that remainder (`N%2` which is 0 or 1) is taken on board again for determining the return value.

#### Recurrence relation

Taking a step back, we can see that  can be expressed as a recurrence relation (this is mathematics):

- <sup>0</sup> = 1
- <sup>2</sup> = <sup>+</sup> =  ·
- <sup>2+1</sup> = <sup>++1</sup> =  ·  ·

As we are given an , we can determine in which of the above three cases we are:

- The first case when  is 0
- The second case when  is even, because then  =  / 2
- The third case when  is odd, because then  = ( − 1) / 2

This recurrence relation is what the code uses to make recursive calls.